How can I combine multiple javascript functions for star rating system
I am running WAMP installed on a Windows 10 PC for a gallery of video clips stored on a local drive. The gallery pages contain thumbs for each video clip and a 5 star rating system.
The star rating system uses a JavaScript module called 'rateIt'. When the star rating is changed, the new value of the rating is updated in a mysql database table.
After several weeks of reading the 'rateIt' documentation, searching the internet for working examples and much trial & error, I finally have the JavaScript code for the star rating of each thumb working as intended.
My problem is each gallery page contains hundreds of thumbs and the JavaScript code for the star rating of each thumb is very repetitive.
How can I use a function stored either on the same page or used from a local js file to reduce the amount of JavaScript code necessary for the star rating and use it for each thumb.
I am sure this is very elementary coding to someone with more experience in JavaScript coding. I have tried to create a function on the page and pass the necessary variables to it, but every attempt breaks the star rating system.
Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated :)
For clarity, the following code is each separate function of the star rating system being used for one of the thumbs:
<div class="thumbContainer">
    <button class="btn-thumb" id="pic10" href="#M1"></button>
    <div class="starContainer">
        <div class="rateit rateit-bg" id="vid147800" data-rateit-step="1" ></div>
        <div><span id="vid147800sid"></span><span id="hover"></span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#vid147800").data('rateit-value', 3);

var tooltipvalues = ['delete', 'poor', 'ok', 'good', 'excellent'];
$("#vid147800").bind("over", function (event, value) { 
    $(this).attr("title", tooltipvalues[value - 1]); });
    
$("#vid147800").bind('rated', function (event, value) { 
    $("#vid147800sid").text("Rating saved " + value); });
    
$("#vid147800").bind("reset", function (event, value) { 
    $("#vid147800sid").text("Rating reset"); });

$("#vid147800").bind('rated reset', function () {  //updates value in database
    var value = $(this).rateit('value');           //when rating is changed
    var IDvid = "vid147800";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/includes/update_ratings.php', //your server side script
        data: { IDvid: IDvid, value: value }, //our data
        type: 'POST'
    });
});
</script>
    </div>
</div>


I used a few variables and combined the functions.
My code for the first two thumbs:
<div class="thumbContainer">
    <button class="btn-thumb" id="pic10" href="#M1"></button>
    <div class="starContainer">
        <div class="rateit rateit-bg" id="vid147800" data-rateit-step="1" ></div>
        <div><span id="vid147800sid"></span><span id="hover"></span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#vid147800").data('rateit-value', 3);  //value is updated from database
$('#vid147800').bind('rated reset', function () {
    var rtDivID = '#vid147800';         //values are updated from
    var IDvid = "vid147800";            //database on page load
    var value = $(this).rateit('value');
    var tooltipvalues = ['delete', 'poor', 'ok', 'good', 'excellent'];
    $(rtDivID).bind("over", function (event, value) { 
        $(this).attr("title", tooltipvalues[value - 1]); });
    $(rtDivID).bind('rated', function (event, value) { 
        $("#vid147800sid").text("Rating saved " + value); });
    $(rtDivID).bind("reset", function (event, value) { 
        $("#vid147800sid").text("Rating reset"); });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/includes/update_ratings.php', //your server side script
        data: { IDvid: IDvid, value: value }, //our data
        type: 'POST'
    });
});
</script>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thumbContainer">
    <button class="btn-thumb" id="pic20" href="#M2"></button>
    <div class="starContainer">
        <div class="rateit rateit-bg" id="vid899128" data-rateit-step="1" ></div>
        <div><span id="vid899128value"></span><span id="hoverVID"></span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#vid899128").data('rateit-value', 2);  //value is updated from database
$("#vid899128").bind('rated reset', function () {
    var rtDivID = '#vid899128';         //values are updated from
    var IDvid = "vid899128";            //database on page load
    var value = $(this).rateit('value');
    var tooltipvalues = ['delete', 'poor', 'ok', 'good', 'excellent'];
    $(rtDivID).bind("over", function (event, value) { 
        $(this).attr("title", tooltipvalues[value - 1]); });
    $(rtDivID).bind('rated', function (event, value) { 
        $("#vid899128value").text("Rating saved " + value); });
    $(rtDivID).bind("reset", function (event, value) { 
        $("#vid899128value").text("Rating reset"); });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/includes/update_ratings.php', //your server side script
        data: { IDvid: IDvid, value: value }, //data
        type: 'POST'
    });
});
</script>
    </div>
</div>

This is the php code which generates each gallery thumb and the star rating  using data stored in a mysql database.
<?php 
include_once 'assets/includes/media_header.php'; 

// Include the database config file 
include_once 'assets/includes/dbConfig.php'; 

// Fetch the info from database 
$query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.user_rating
            FROM xhtmlall t1
            LEFT JOIN star_ratings t2
            ON t1.IDvid = t2.IDvid
            WHERE page = '1' ORDER BY Idmstr";
$count = 0;
$result = $conn->query($query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows ($result );
if ($count > 0) { 
    echo $count . "<br>".PHP_EOL; 
    while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div class="thumbContainer">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<button class="btn-thumb" id='."'pic".$row['IDpic']."' href=".'"#M'.$row['IDdiv'].'"></button>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<div class="starContainer">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<div class="rateit" id="'.$row['IDvid'].'" data-rateit-step="1" ></div>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<div><span id="'.$row['IDvid'].'sid"></span><span id="hover"></span></div>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '$("#'.$row['IDvid'].'").data("rateit-value", '.$row['user_rating'].');'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '$("#'.$row['IDvid'].'").bind("rated reset", function () {'.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'var rtDivID = "#'.$row['IDvid'].'";'.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'var IDvid = "'.$row['IDvid'].'";'.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'var value = $(this).rateit("value");'.PHP_EOL;
        echo "var tooltipvalues = ['delete', 'poor', 'ok', 'good', 'excellent'];".PHP_EOL;
        echo '$(rtDivID).bind("over", function (event, value) {$(this).attr("title", tooltipvalues[value - 1]); });'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '$(rtDivID).bind("rated", function (event, value) {$("#'.$row['IDvid'].'sid").text("Rating saved " + value); });'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '$(rtDivID).bind("reset", function (event, value) {$("#'.$row['IDvid'].'sid").text("Rating reset"); });'.PHP_EOL;
        echo "$.ajax({url: 'assets/includes/update_ratings.php', data: { IDvid: IDvid, value: value }, type: 'POST' });".PHP_EOL;
        echo '});'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '</script>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '</div></div>'.PHP_EOL;


Use event delegation. See this page

please add more precisions about your rateIt "module" ; also read : -1-
asking a good question -2-
minimal reproducible example
-3-visit help section

if you don't mean to refactor your logic using a smarter approach, you may just use those ids as parameter of a function that will bind the event listeners to the passed .thumbContainer and then call such function in a loop iterating over all .thumbContainer elements found in the document once on page ready. Plus I suggest you to make your html template .thumbContainer so that it doesn't use ids at all if not just the vid##### and just rely on classes

Can you add the PHP used to generate the original page?

@Professor Abronsius    php code added

Is $row['IDdiv'] a typo?

@Professor Abronsius  No typo

@Professor Abronsius  No typo.  Using the php code, I retrieve necessary information from the MySQL database. It is only the delivery method.  Do you have any suggestions if its possible to reduce the repetitive JavaScript code using a function called from an external file? I am a novice with JavaScript code and the suggestions so far seem outside my current experience level. The code provided works as intended. I am only trying to improve it.

@ Diego D   I am open to using a smarter approach. I appreciate your suggestion, but as a novice, I haven't managed to find a starting point of a how to use the approach you suggest. I am a beginner and learn best from example. Could you provide any examples of the method you describe?

Yes, you should be able to use one single script block for this.

$("#vid147800").data('rateit-value', 3);

I can't see this value getting accessed anywhere in the JS you have shown - so presumably, the rating script itself will read this, when it gets initialized afterwards - same as it presumably does with the data-rateit-step="1" attribute on the rating container div.
So remove this line, and put a data-rateit-value="3" attribute onto the div instead. (With the respective rating value for the current element, of course.)

<div><span id="vid147800sid"></span><span id="hover"></span></div>

That first span should get a class, for easier selection - let's use rateit-sid here. And that id="hover" is likely duplicated multiple times, when you create this in a loop - can't tell what that is supposed to be used for to begin with though.
Then the rest should boil down to something like this:
var tooltipvalues = ['delete', 'poor', 'ok', 'good', 'excellent'];

$(".rateit").on("over", function (event, value) { 
    $(this).attr("title", tooltipvalues[value - 1]);
});
    
$(".rateit").on('rated', function (event, value) { 
    $(this).closest(".starContainer").find(".rateit-sid").text("Rating saved " + value);
});
    
$(".rateit").on("reset", function (event, value) { 
    $(this).closest(".starContainer").find(".rateit-sid").text("Rating reset");
});

$(".rateit").on('rated reset', function () {  //updates value in database
    var value = $(this).rateit('value');           //when rating is changed
    var IDvid = $(this).attr("id"); // get directly from the id attribute of the element
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/includes/update_ratings.php', //your server side script
        data: { IDvid: IDvid, value: value }, //our data
        type: 'POST'
    });
});


instead of selecting individual elements by ID, we apply this to all .rateit elements
instead of .bind(), which is deprecated, I used .on() here
selection of the span for output happens by going up from the current element to the .starContainer ancestor first, and then selecting the .rateit-sid element inside that

This is untested, and might still contain minor errors or typos. And if you put this into an external script, make sure it loads after the DOM is ready, or wrap it all into a "ready" handler, https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

$("#vid147800").data('rateit-value', 3);     This is setting the current star rating value.    The html version is <div class="rateit rateit-bg" id="vid147800" data-rateit-step="1"  data-ratit-value='3';>     The value is retrieved from MySQL database

Thank you so much. I have the code working perfectly. I followed all of your recommended changes, placed the JavaScript code in a js file and then load the script  at the bottom of the page.  Code works fine with or without the span id="hover", so I deleted it without any ill effects. It was used in the rateit example code for the tooltips function. I'm not sure what its intended use is but it works fine without it. Thanks again, your help is greatly appriciated. :)  I tried to upvote answer but my reputation isn't high enough.
